# MenuItem.SetOnActionExpandListener() with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem

Like basically everything with Kotlin Android Development, I am having trouble finding an example of how to utilize the `MenuItem.SetOnActionExpandListener()` in Kotlin.

My `menuItem` is a search action, and I need to trigger a function whenever the user closes the search. However, when searching how to do all of this, the only examples I find are in Java with zero information about how to do it in Kotlin...

I am attempting to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459882/android-actionbarsherlock-searchview-setoncloselistener-is-not-working), but I can't seem to figure out how to do this with Kotlin...

How do I convert that solution into Kotlin syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(object : MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener {
  override fun onMenuItemActionExpand(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    // TODO: do something...
    return true
  }

  override fun onMenuItemActionCollapse(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    // TODO: do something...
   return true
  }
})
```

Comment: `object` was the part I was missing when attempting this! Thanks for your help!